# Check if a durable queue in rabbitMQ has data in it?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, message-queue, kill

I have some durable queues running in the broker. At some point, I want to check if the queue has got any data in it and close or kill that queue if it is empty.

I am using java to code the senders and receivers.
I know which all queues are present in the broker.

Suggest your way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the `GetResponse` object value for getting the info that whether the queue has something in it or not. If `GetResponse` is null, you can delete the queue, considering the queue as empty.

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        Connection con = factory.newConnection();
        rabbitChannel = con.createChannel();
GetResponse response = rabbitChannel.basicGet(QUEUE_NAME, BOOLEAN_NOACK);
if(response != null){
String body = new String(responseQuestion.getBody());
// do whatever you want to do here
}
else{
rabbitChannel.queueDelete(QUEUE_NAME);
}
```

OR

Use this `queueDelete(java.lang.String queue, boolean ifUnused, boolean ifEmpty)`

This will automatically check whether if queue is `empty` and `not_in_use` based on `boolean` you provided in arguments & delete it accordingly.

Comment: how exactly does ifUnused boolean work? For me its worthy if it checks that no producers are currently connected to it and then close. Is it that way?

Comment: @AnilKumar `ifUnused ` should be set as  `true` if the queue should be deleted only if not in use, similar is the case with `ifEmpty`